# What is the difference between Gwibber's Home and Messages?

Tags: gwibber

In the newest version of Gwibber, there are several tabs. I get the Replies, Private Messages, etc., however, I can't seem to find what the difference is between Home and Messages. On seems to refresh more than the other, or something, but other than that they seem to hold the same content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Ken VanDine in a thread I found in a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/gwibber/+bug/960670):

> The "Home" stream is everything, an aggregation of all the other
>   streams.  The others are there to help you filter the results and just
>   view what you want...  The "Replies" tab does include mentions, not just replies to your posts.

A fuller explanation is here, in another [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/gwibber/+bug/994088):

> In regard to which stream is selected by default, in the past gwibber
>   did default to selecting the all messages tab. However, lots of people
>   complained because it included streams like links, which for facebook
>   at least, includes posts from facebook games. So depending who your
>   friends are, lots of noise there. The rationale behind to changing
>   that to default to "messages" was it was really a stream of your
>   friends "status updates". Which is something people seem most
>   interesting in seeing. I am not opposed to changing it back to default
>   to all messages, but we need some consensious on that, we can't make
>   everyone happy.
>
> In general we need to spend some time looking at what we call the
>   streams, we have generalized them between all the services, but
>   "messages" isn't really messages, it is "status updates".